# Управление

Tags: управление

Тогда с рельсов сошли 21 цистерна с газом.

Сошли или сошла? Если сошла, то согласуется с числительным, если же сошли - то с цистернами. Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1):

При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один, сказуемое, как правило, ставится в форме единственного числа, например: ***Двадцать один делегат прибыл на совещание; ...было подано сразу тридцать одно заявление (Шолохов).*** Форма множественного числа данной конструкции может быть обусловлена контекстом, например: ***Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом*** (сказуемое-глагол встретились указывает на взаимное действие, которое выражается формой множественного числа); 
В вашем случае правильно: сошла. Т.к. подлежащее цистерна обозначает неодушевленный предмет. Т.е. цистерны сошли разом, все вместе.

Comment: А откуда вы взяли информацию? Не можете подкрепить ссылкой?

Comment: [Розенталь Д. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке...](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

Answer (score 0):

"Тогда с рельсов сошла 21 цистерна с газом". Это согласование по форме, которое считалось основным вариантом для числительных на "один".

Однако в последнее время укрепляется тенденция согласования по смыслу: "Тогда с рельсов сошли 21 цистерна с газом".

Comment: Согласование по смыслу не относится к этому пункту. Ср. следующее предложение: Двадцать один студент не явились на экзамен (ЭМОЦИОНАЛЬНО ОКРАШЕННЫЙ РАЗГОВОРНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ, подчеркивающий количество отсутствовавших).

Comment: При ответе я фактически цитирую "Практическую стилистику современного русского языка" (РАН, 2012 г.): "...обычно - ед.число, но в последнее время вследствие возрастающего влияния согласования по смыслу возможно согласование во мн.числе"). Сошла одна цистерна, (двадцать одна) цистерна - формальное согласование по ед. числу, а по смыслу здесь мн. число. Не думаю, что в этом случае отражается какая-то особенная эмоциональность.

Comment: У Розенталя  цитируемый Вами пункт относится к словом большинство, ряд, и.т.п. А словом один предлагаемый Вами вариант(согласованию по смыслу)  относится к  (ЭМОЦИОНАЛЬНО ОКРАШЕННОМУ РАЗГОВОРНОМУ ВАРИАНТУ). И я с этим пунктом согласен.Там говорится, что единственное число характерно для обеденного действия, а множественное для раздельного. Там выше я указал ссылку.

Comment: Мне кажется, не стоит слишком много семантики вкладывать в нестандартное сочетание с числительным "один". В действительности мы просто пытаемся выбрать более подходящий вариант при отсутствии сочетаемости в обоих, а также как-то унифицировать его, сделать привычным для слуха.
____

Попробуйте скачать книгу "Практическая стилистика современного русского языка": http://vasiliya2011.ucoz.ru/news/skachat_knigu_prakticheskaja_stilistika_sovremennogo_russkogo_jazyka_julij_belchikov/2014-02-05-360